# Understanding the method removeChar

Tags: java, methods, char

At school we were looking at a code for removing a character from a string. 
I have a problem understanding the for loop in this code.
What happens if `word.charAt(i)` is equal to c? If `word.charAt(i)` is not equal to c the character is printed out. (`words.charAt(i)` gets printed out)
But if it is equal to c, where in the code does the character get removed?

Thank you in advance for your help. And I'm sorry for my bad English.
This is the code our teacher gave us:

```
String removeChar(String word, char c) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i<word.length();i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) !=c) {
      result += word.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: "where in the code does the character get removed" It's not that the character is removed, it's that it's never added into `result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read this code like:

1. Create an empty String `result`.
2. For each letter from `word`, check if it is not 'c' character. **Only if it is not** 'c', append this letter to `result` String (add this letter at the end of `result` String). If currently checked character **is equal** to 'c', do **nothing**.
3. When loop reaches the end of `word`, return `result` String.

By the way, appending `String` in a loop using `+=` operator is not that efficient like using class `StringBuilder` and its `append()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The char is not really removed;
it's simply not append (result += word.charAt(i)) into the string result. 
In this way the string that is returned by the method is formed only by the chars that are different from char c.

Answer (score 0):

This code just creates new String object (see variable *result*). At end of function this new string contains only characters which do not equal to *c*. Next it string returns as result of function.

Java strings is not mutable, so this is only way to "modify" string - create brand new string.

Answer (score -1):

Character is not actually removed its just been appended to the empty new string(String result = "";) which you have declared above,when word doesn't contain the character 'c', then those characters are getting appended to result, finally you are retrieving that 'Result' string not 'Word',it still containing same value which you have sent.